# How to add an optional memeber in a regular C # modal class to avoid duplicate entity class

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, wpf, c#-4.0

Could you please look into a C# design problem (see below) and suggest the right approach? I am not sure how to handle this situation.

I have a class called ClassA like this:

```
    public class ClassA
    {
        public string Name;
        public string Address;
        public string Details;
    }
```

for which I am creating an object like this:

```
ClassA call = new ClassA ();
```

and then setting values on run time like this:

```
 call .Name= "Praveen";
```

and sending it over to some client using a service call.

My requirement is that I have to send another call which has the same data member and an additional one only and I want to utilize the existing ClassA so that my code is not duplicated everywhere.
By using an `if/else`, I should be able to do this.

So ClassA would become something like:

```
public class ClassA 
{
    public string Name;
    public string Address;
    public string Details;
    //Optional 
    Public String Phone
}
```

so that If I set the value of phone then it is sent in my xml call, otherwise it should not appear in the xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<CallA xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Name>Prav </Name>
  <Address>Zurich </Address>
  <Details>KEMP Tower</Details>
</CallA>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add ShouldSerializeXXX() method to your class to handle this. I did a quick test and it worked. Here is the code snippet. Test with or without ShouldSerializePhoneNumbers() method to notice difference.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {          
            SerializationHelper.SerializeTest();
            Console.Read();
        }
    }

    public static class SerializationHelper
    {
        [Serializable]
        public class ClassA
        {
            public string Name;
            public string Address;
            public string Details;

            public List<string> PhoneNumbers = new List<string>();

            public bool ShouldSerializePhoneNumbers()
            {
                if (PhoneNumbers == null || PhoneNumbers.Count <= 0)
                    return false;
                else
                    return true;
            }
        }

        public static void SerializeTest()
        {
            ClassA call = new ClassA();
            call.Name = "Praveen";

            XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ClassA));

            TextWriter writer = new StringWriter();
            ser.Serialize(writer, call);

            string xml = writer.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: @user2519971 you can write your optional conditions in shouldserialize() method.